# Is it possible to wrap C enums in Rust?

Tags: c, rust

Is it possible to wrap C enums in Rust?

For example [C enum example](https://github.com/horde3d/Horde3D/blob/master/Horde3D/Bindings/C++/Horde3D.h#L89)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, with no changes (other than whitespace to fit in with prevailing Rust style):

```
enum List {
    MaxLogLevel = 1,
    MaxNumMessages,
    TrilinearFiltering,
    MaxAnisotropy,
    TexCompression,
    SRGBLinearization,
    LoadTextures,
    FastAnimation,
    ShadowMapSize,
    SampleCount,
    WireframeMode,
    DebugViewMode,
    DumpFailedShaders,
    GatherTimeStats
}

fn main() {
    println!("{} {} {}",
             MaxLogLevel as uint,
             SampleCount as uint,
             GatherTimeStats as uint);
}
```

Prints `1 10 14`.

Comment: You made a change! The `{` is on its own line in the original. :P

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Fine! We'll have it your way. :P

Comment: There's a second change! The indentation is different! :P

Comment: Thanks but I thought that C optimizes the enums so we never know the real size of the enum, has this changed?

Comment: @MaikKlein, not really. [This (currently bitrotted) PR](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/pull/9613) is giving users control over the size of the enums which will make this easier, but, in general, C APIs that use enums are very hard to interface with from other languages (precisely because C compilers are mostly free to choose the size of the enum as they wish).

Comment: @dbaupp Does this mean that it is impossible to interface with a C lib that uses enums? Or is there a work around?

Comment: @MaikKlein, it's hard without forcing the C compiler with which the C lib is built to use a predictable size for enums (e.g. always the smallest possible size, or always `int`).

Comment: If u want to fit size with C u should use `#[repr(C)]`?