# How to specify the representation type for an enum in Rust to interface with C++?

Tags: enums, rust

Is there a way I can make a C++ style enumeration with explicit representation type in Rust? Example:

```
enum class Number: int16_t {
    Zero, One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine
};
```

If not, is there another way I can organize variables like that? I am interfacing with an external library, so specifying the type is important. I know I could just do:

```
type Number = int16_t;
let One: Number = 1;
let Two: Number = 2;
let Three: Number = 3;
```

But that introduces a lot of redundancy, in my opinion;

---

Note this question is not a duplicate of [Is it possible to wrap C enums in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433827/is-it-possible-to-wrap-c-enums-in-rust) as it is about wrapping C++, not wrapping C.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to wrap C enums in Rust?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433827/is-it-possible-to-wrap-c-enums-in-rust)

Comment: @fimor That question is about C style enums, which are different from C++ ones.

Comment: Ah, good thing you updated the question then :)

Comment: @JeroenBollen, noticed you removed "when interfacing C++" from title, is this question about interfacing C++ or not? Otherwise it looks like a duplicate of "possible to wrap C enums in Rust?"

Comment: @ideasman42 I rolled back your redundant edits which did not contribute anything to the OP, however the C++ in the title can be justified.

Comment: This questions purpose is still a bit vague to me. Rust doesn't have C++ FFI, so assume this would be converted to a C int16_t and go via C's FFI ? https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/602

Comment: @ideasman42 I posted this thread 2 years ago, I have no idea what my intent was at the time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can specify a representation for the enum.

```
#[repr(i16)]
enum Foo {
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
}
```